# Drawing diagrams in LaTeX with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pdftex, tikz-styles

I am new to drawing diagrams in LaTeX. I want to be able to draw the diagram below in LaTeX for my beamer presentation but I am finding it a bit challenging. Can anyone please help? 
[image]

This is what i have been able to do so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt,serif]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{CambridgeUS}}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[blue,thick] (15,15)  ++(45:1) arc (45:-45:4);
 \filldraw[blue,thick] (16.2,15) circle(0.5cm);
 \draw[blue,thick] (16.2,15) rectangle(25cm,5);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

I don't really mind if the colours are different. Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420362/annotated-itemization-with-beamer/422965#422965 could be a starting point

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

color of borders and fills of circles can be simply adjusted to your taste. to  preserve simplicity of code, the color of rectangles is (so far) fixed:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{CambridgeUS}}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign} % i haven't installed
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
C/.style = {circle,
           draw=#1, thick,
           fill=#1!30,
           minimum size=12mm
           },
R/.style = {rectangle,
           draw=gray, thick,
           fill=gray!30,
           minimum height=9mm,
           text width=12cm-#1cm,
           inner xsep=8mm,
           align=left,
           font=\Large,
           anchor=west
           }
                    ]
%
\draw[gray, line width=2mm] ( 60:4) arc (60:-60:4);
%
 \node[R=2.83] at ( 45:4) {Agra}; %  4*cos(45)
 \node[R=3.86] at ( 15:4) {Fran}; %  4*cos(15)
 \node[R=3.86] at (-15:4) {Brana};%  4*cos(15)
 \node[R=2.83] at (-45:4) {Grad}; %  4*cos(45)
%
\node[C=blue]  at ( 45:4) {};
\node[C=green] at ( 15:4) {};
\node[C=olive] at (-15:4) {};
\node[C=gray]  at (-45:4) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**addedmdum:** 
small changes of above example that enable simple coloring of rectangles:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{CambridgeUS}}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
C/.style = {% Circle
            circle,
            draw=#1, thick,
            fill=#1!30,
            minimum size=11mm
           },
R/.style args = {#1:#2}{% Rectangle       <---
            rectangle, rounded corners, % <---
            draw=#2, very thin,
            top color= #2!20,           % <---
            bottom color= #2!20,        % <---
            middle color= #2!60,        % <---
            minimum height=9mm,
            text width=12cm-#1cm,
            inner xsep=9mm,
            align=left,
            font=\Large,
            anchor=west
           },
                    ]
%
\draw[gray, line width=2mm] ( 60:4) arc (60:-60:4);
%
 \node[R=2.83:blue]     at ( 45:4) {Agra}; %  4*cos(45)
 \node[R=3.86:green]    at ( 15:4) {Fran}; %  4*cos(15)
 \node[R=3.86:olive]    at (-15:4) {Brana};%  4*cos(15)
 \node[R=2.83:gray]     at (-45:4) {Grad}; %  4*cos(45)
%
\node[C=blue]  at ( 45:4) {};
\node[C=green] at ( 15:4) {};
\node[C=olive] at (-15:4) {};
\node[C=gray]  at (-45:4) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what I needed. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

The `smartdiagram` package can do something similar:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\smartdiagram[descriptive diagram]
{
{, Agra},
{, Fran},
{, Bran},
{, Grad},
}
\end{center}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for suggesting the `smartdiagram` package. I know this would be useful sometime.