# Align section and subsection navigation in beamer

Tags: beamer, navigation

I want to include the subsection navigation on the section slide (through `\insertsubsectionnavigation`) and align it with the current section. I am having trouble aligning them properly though, see below.

[image]

Any thoughts on how to align it such that "Method A" is on the same line as "Methodology"?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43]{beamer}

\usepackage{pbox}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{%
        \usebeamerfont{sectionpage}\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlepages}\raggedright%
        \huge\insertsectionhead%
      \hspace{0.1\textwidth}%
      \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \large\insertsubsectionnavigation{\linewidth}
      \end{minipage}
}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{%
    \pbox[c][4ex][c]{0.2\textwidth}{%
      %
      \color{black!75}\Large\centering\insertsectionhead%
    }\hspace*{1pt}%
}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot}{%
    \footnotesize\hspace*{-1pt}\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \pbox[c][4ex][c]{\textwidth}{%
            \centering\small\insertsubsectionhead%
    }\hspace*{1pt}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot shaded}{%
    \footnotesize \hspace*{-1pt}\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \pbox[c][4ex][c]{\textwidth}{%
      %
      \color{black!75}\small\insertsubsectionhead%
    }\hspace*{1pt}%
}

\AtBeginSection[]{%
        {\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue!50}%
        \frame{%
            \huge\insertsectionnavigation{0.6\linewidth}{}{}%
            \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}}}%
        }

\AtBeginSubsection[]{{\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue!50}\frame{\mbox{}\hspace{0.1\textwidth}Subsection \thesubsection\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}}}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Overview}

\begin{frame}{Overview}

\end{frame}

\section{Methodology}

\subsection{Method A}

\begin{frame}{Method A is good}

    Total: \inserttotalframenumber

\end{frame}

\subsection*{Method B}

\begin{frame}{Method B is better}

    Because it is better.

\end{frame}

\subsection*{Method C}

\begin{frame}{Method C is the best}

    Because it is the best.

\end{frame}

\section{Results}

\subsection*{Preliminary results}

\begin{frame}{Early results}

    Not good.

\end{frame}

\subsection*{Final results}

\begin{frame}{These results are beautiful.}

    Perfect.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick hack:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43]{beamer}

\usepackage{pbox}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{%
        \usebeamerfont{sectionpage}\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlepages}\raggedright%
        \huge\insertsectionhead%
      \hspace{0.1\textwidth}%
      \begin{minipage}[b][.5\textheight][t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \vspace*{4.3cm}
        \large\insertsubsectionnavigation{\linewidth}
      \end{minipage}
}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{%
    \pbox[c][4ex][c]{0.2\textwidth}{%
      %
      \color{black!75}\Large\centering\insertsectionhead%
    }\hspace*{1pt}%
}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=white}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot}{%
    \footnotesize\hspace*{-1pt}\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \pbox[c][4ex][c]{\textwidth}{%
            \centering\small\insertsubsectionhead%
    }\hspace*{1pt}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot shaded}{%
    \footnotesize \hspace*{-1pt}\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \pbox[c][4ex][c]{\textwidth}{%
      %
      \color{black!75}\small\insertsubsectionhead%
    }\hspace*{1pt}%
}

\AtBeginSection[]{%
        {\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue!50}%
        \frame{%
            \huge\insertsectionnavigation{0.6\linewidth}{}{}%
            \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}}}%
        }

\AtBeginSubsection[]{{\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue!50}\frame{\mbox{}\hspace{0.1\textwidth}Subsection \thesubsection\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}}}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Overview}

\begin{frame}{Overview}

\end{frame}

\section{Methodology} % if this does not have a star, it works.

\subsection{Method A}
    \subsection{Method A}
        \subsection{Method A}
            \subsection{Method A}
                \subsection{Method A}
                    \subsection{Method A}

\begin{frame}{Method A is good}

    Total: \inserttotalframenumber

\end{frame}

\subsection*{Method B}

\begin{frame}{Method B is better}

    Because it is better.

\end{frame}

\subsection*{Method C}

\begin{frame}{Method C is the best}

    Because it is the best.

\end{frame}

\section{Results}

\subsection*{Preliminary results}

\begin{frame}{Early results}

    Not good.

\end{frame}

\subsection*{Final results}

\begin{frame}{These results are beautiful.}

    Perfect.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sure that works, but if I now change aspect ratio, font size, or something else, it is again misaligned.

Comment: @maero21 To accommodate for different font sizes, you could replace the `4.3cm` with a unit relative to the font size, e.g. `1em` (replace 1 by a suitable value)

Comment: @maero21 If you want more control, you could combine https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/422965/36296 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303968/36296 to create your own navigation using tikz

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up just using a `tableofcontents`.